# Matlib Add-on Gone Wrong

Tags: add-on

I just tried to add a MatLib add-on. I followed the instructions from this link:

https://sites.google.com/site/aleonserra/home/scripts/matlib-vx.

Everything seemed to go fine but then I tried to do install addon from file and I selected the **init**.py (which I probably wasn't supposed to do). I've done add-ons from file before but it's been a while so I was pretty stupid in this situation.

I tried to kind of follow the demo at that link but it was in another language so it was hard to follow. My regular functionality in blender seems fine (just the add-on doesn't work) but I am just wondering if I need to do any maintenance on my files, and I want to get this add-on working. I could show you the materials file they gave me and how the crashing occurs when you use the add-on but I don't think it will do anything because it looks at the file specifically from my directory.  Will post if needed.

What're your guys' thoughts?

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions on the link you provided? Is the problem that it doesn't install or that it doesn't work properly?

Comment: It seems to be just an add-on that supports the already written in System:Material Library add-on.  At least I think that is a standard Blender add-on now.  So I think that I just messed up the files so it won't support that add-on now but idk.  I was able to click the add-on and it does show up in my material tab of the properties editor. @RayMairlot